# Cannot boot after changing locale

Tags: 12.04, boot, mount, locale, amazon-ec2

After I changed my locale and rebooted, now I get this error:

```
[    1.863178] init: mountall main process (223) terminated with status 2
Filesystem check or mount failed.
A maintenance shell will now be started.
CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and continue booting after re-trying
filesystems.  Any further errors will be ignored
Give root password for maintenance
(or type Control-D to continue):
```

Btw, this is and Amazon AWS EC2 instance, so I don't have access to actually pressing Control-D. I'm stuck here, how can just changing the local result in the instance not being able to boot at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of debugging the issue, I detached the volume from this instance and attached it as a secondary volume in another instnace I had access to.

It turns out that, by mistake, I entered to quotes at the end of a line in `/etc/default/locale` file, as follows:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8""
```

Aparently, this caused the disk not being able to mount. I corrected the file removing the extra quote:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

After that, I reattached the volume to the original instance and it booted up!

If anyone could share the technical reason about why a syntax error in the locale file can cause the disk not to mount, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This article pointed my in the right direction: http://www.samundra.com.np/solved-mount-of-root-filesystem-failed-ubuntu/1239